# zxing scanning region not accurate

Tags: android, zxing, scanning

In my project, the scanning area (the box that is non-shady) seems not consistent with the true scanning region where barcode is scanned. The true region seems to be a bit above the box, since I have to place the barcode a bit above the red line (I changed my zxing to portrait mode) in order for the barcode to be read successfully.

So I wonder if the framingRect in CameraManager is the actual scanning area, or it is just a non-shady box? If so, how should I do to move the non-shady box up so that it align with the actual scanning area,  (or vice-versa would be fine as well).

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue so I am wondering if you perhaps could give me a clue by explaining what was wrong in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the scanning region is the same as the reticle. Have a look at the source code. I am not sure why you think it isn't. It does not only scan on the red line.

Comment: Bit late but thought I'd add something for future readers. I came across similar a while back and it turned out (on my LG G3) that the camera image is squashed slightly when the status and button bars are visible, yet the coordinates calculated in the app for the reticule are based on the full screen. Simplest fix was just to run in full screen and go with it. Could be why the original poster's issue seemed to disappear on its own.